# If an abstract entity has it's own custom class, is that class usually abstract, too?

Tags: iphone, core-data

If an abstract entity has it's own custom class, is that class usually abstract, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C does not have an abstract class definition at this time.  Therefore the subclass for an entity is not abstract but you can treat it as such if you so choose.

There is no one-to-one relationship between entities and classes so you can have one class that is being used by multiple entities if you so choose.

Answer (score 2):

Classes only are abstract if they are marked with the keyword `abstract`. So the inner custom class may be or may not be abstract, it's independent of its "container".

Comment: are you talking about core data?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary. It depends.

Answer (score 0):

a cladd needs to declare abstract untill all of these method have implementation,it depends on if your custom classes are concrete then no....